# Issue with Top corners rounded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Section 0 (cell separated & single selection)

[image]

Section 1 (cell grouped & multi-selection)
[image]

I use below code to Round top Corners.

```
//roundTop Method
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                                   byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    maskLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self drawBorderLayer:maskPath];

-(void)drawBorderLayer:(UIBezierPath *)maskPath {
    if (self.layer.borderWidth > 0) {

        CAShapeLayer*   frameLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        frameLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskPath.lineWidth = self.layer.borderWidth * 2;
        frameLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        frameLayer.strokeColor = self.layer.borderColor;
        frameLayer.fillColor = nil;
        [self.layer addSublayer:frameLayer];

    }
}
```

- I have a problem with Rounded corner. I added `drawBorderLayer` method to draw Border for rounded portion, but it doesn't have enough width. (Green Arrow - A)
- When I scroll down the rounded cell is replaced in Another cell(I can't proper reuse the cell). ie., How to reset my normal view after Applying cornered mask? *NB: I tried `self.layer.mask = nil;`, but not Working*

My `cellForRowAtIndexpath`

```
if (sectionModel.sectionStyle == SMFilterSectionStyleGrouped) {
        if ([[sectionModel.cells lastObject] isEqual:cellModel]) {
            [cell roundBottom];
        }else if(indexPath.row == 0) {
            [cell roundTop];
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about applying the rounding to the tableview instead of the cells?

Comment: These are cells in my second section of tableview. I used the same cell in first section & in that case the cell have padding. Please check updated question